# Excel : Auto email table row corresponding to email address

Tags: excel, email, automation, mailmerge

I have an email sent out that looks like the following :-

[Email Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzY63.jpg)

The following is a picture of the excel file I have from which I pick the table in for the Email Body
[Excel File for Email Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhqAg.jpg)

I pick up values from A1 to C1 as well as relevant row and send to the email address in the corresponding Row in Column D.

For example, I picked up A1 to C2 from Excel File and sent it to the email address in D2.

Is there a way to automate this using Excel VBA or mailmerge? Either would suffice. I have about 60-70 such lines coming in everyday and automating this would result in a huge time saving.

Thank you in advance to anyone who responds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is exactly what mailmerge does.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have been trying to do it with mailmerge for the longest time, however, I cannot find anything specific online that will automatically fill in the rows in the email according to the email address. If I could find something of the likes I would be grateful